# Distinguishing between bounds of probability mass function?

Tags: probability, statistics

What is the difference between $P(a< X\leq b)$ and $P(a\leq X\leq b)$, and what would the corresponding formulas be?

Comment: Well.... for $P(a<X\leq b)$ you have that $a$ is not included in the desired event and for $P(a\leq X\leq b)$ you have that $a$ *is* included in the desired event.  The corresponding formulae depend on the specific distribution of $X$.  The relationship between the two is that $P(a\leq X\leq b)=P(X=a)+P(a<X\leq b)$

Answer (score 2):

$$P(a \leq X \leq b) = P(a < X \leq b) +P(X=a)$$

If you have access to the CDF function, $$P(a<X \leq b)=P(X \leq b)-P(X \leq a)$$

For continuous random variable, since $P(X=a)=0$, $P(a \leq X \leq b) = P(a < X \leq b).$